# How can i maintain side images in the Android xml?

Tags: android, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
            >
//Relative Layout for entire controls

           <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/homeicon"
            >
        </ImageView>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="230dip" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Appoiments">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    //within linear-layout i am using the button and image view for displaying the image and button control

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="70dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/appoiments"
            >
        </ImageView>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="230dip" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Service Type">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="140dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/carstatus"
            >
        </ImageView>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="160dip" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Enter Time">
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="160dip" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Enter Date">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="190dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/waitinglounge"
            >
        </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="240dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/pricelist"
            >
        </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="280dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/soffers"
            >
        </ImageView>
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="230dip" 
            android:layout_height="65dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Enter Special Instructions">
        </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="325dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/caracess"
            >
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="365dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/testdrive"
            >
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="410dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/referfriend"
            >
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="425dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/feedback"
            >
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="465dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="95dip" 
            android:layout_height="45dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/carmaitananceguide"
            >
        </ImageView>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
           android:layout_width="180dip" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
             android:paddingTop="15dip"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:background="#959090"
             android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
             android:text="Submit">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:paddingTop="510dip"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="100dip" 
            android:layout_height="40dip" 
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/alerts"
            >
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 but the images is not aligned properly my need is the side images bar is continues to the through out the application when i am move any screen the side images view is constant how can i achieve it in the Android xml.the side bar images is show in the all the screen whenever i select the any of the services from the side bar .the images is came from app draw-able folder

Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: side images means? Whats happening with this XML layout?

Comment: the gap is between images is coming more ?

Comment: i want maintain that side images through the app?

Comment: Please be more specific. What you want to implement exactly? Whats happening with your this xml layout? Otherwise how can we help you out without knowing your question exactly.